# See blank white page after adding row in column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create a login page. In this page, I need to have "forgot your password" and "remember me" in a same line, so I used row. When I hot reload it, it shows me a blank, white page.
I tried a row in container and adding that container to my column and still having that black page.
It has no problem if I add them normally (in two line), but I want them in a same line.

(If you have any suggestion for better and cleaner code, please tell me. I accept any suggestion)

Here is my code after a lot of changes:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const List<String> list = <String>['one', 'two'];

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  get value => null;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final logo = Image.asset(
      'assets/logo.png',
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
    );

    final user = Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 10),
        child: const Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Username',
                floatingLabelAlignment: FloatingLabelAlignment.center,
                border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                suffixIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.person,
                  color: Colors.orange,
                ),
              ),
            )));

    final password = Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, top: 10, right: 40, bottom: 10),
        child: const Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Password',
                suffixIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.lock,
                  color: Colors.orange,
                ),
              ),
            )));

    final forgetting = TextButton(
      onPressed: null,
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        primary: Colors.red,
      ),
      child: const Text(
        'Forgotten password',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
      ),
    );

    final rememberMe = CheckboxListTile(
      value: false,
      onChanged: (Text) {
        print('text');
      },
      title: Text('/ remember me'),
    );

    DropdownButton static = DropdownButton(
      items: const [
        DropdownMenuItem(child: Text('text1')),
        DropdownMenuItem(child: Text('text2'))
      ],
      onChanged: (value) {},
    );

    final enterButton = Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, right: 40, top: 0, bottom: 10),
        width: double.infinity,
        child: TextButton(
            onPressed: null,
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
            ),
            child: const Text('Enter')));

    final rules = Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: const [
        Checkbox(
          value: false,
          onChanged: null,
          checkColor: Colors.orange,
        ),
        Text('Rules')
      ],
    );

    final fingerPrint = FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(255, 165, 0, 0.3),
      child: const Icon(Icons.fingerprint, color: Colors.orange, size: 50),
    );

    const version = Text(
      'Version: 1.4.7',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange),
    );

    
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          logo,
          user,
          password,
          Container(
              child: Row(
            children: [rememberMe, forgetting],
          )),
          enterButton,
          rules,
          fingerPrint,
          const Spacer(),
          version
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Wrap the Children of the Row in an Expanded or Flexible widget

```
 .........    
     password,
      Row(
        children: [Expanded(child: rememberMe), Expanded(child: forgetting)],
      ),
      enterButton, 
  .........
```

Comment: you  can checkout this https://medium.flutterdevs.com/expanded-and-flexible-in-flutter-68f58c7f3ce0 to see When to use Flexible or Expanded Widget